# Is it halal to become a plastic surgeon in the modern world?

Tags: practical-islam, work

Asslamualikum,
Dear Brothers / Sisters, 
I am doing medical and wanted to know weather I can choose plastic surgery as my specialty. In the modern day plastic surgery can also be used to beautify women and men with fixtures on their skin. So I was kind of having a doubt here.......

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information about our site and the stackexchange model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your inquiry: There are fatwas showing the use or need of plastic surgery so saying it is haram is rather false-faced.